# Is there a enviornmental variable for the path to header files?

Tags: files, compiling, libraries

I am installing some software, and I get an error that says Nux.h not found.
I have the Nux.h header, in my downloads file folder, but I don't know where it should go. where do ".h" files go?

Also, is there a system variable that describes the path where header files are stored?

Comment: What build tool do you use? `make`, `ant`, `maven`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C header files are usually stored in the `/usr/include` directory. So for example the `#include <stdio.h>` includes the header file from there.

If your file is not there, you can use relative paths to specify the location, e.g.

```
#include "main-header.h"
```

includes the `main-header.h` file from the current working directory.

---

By the way, if you install the `libnux-4.0-dev` package, it should install the headers into `/usr/include`, and it will also add the binaries, which will be necessary for linking.